# Why does the last access time change for a file when it gets stored in a list or object?

Tags: python, file, lastaccesstime

I'm trying to look at a directory and determine the last time a file was accessed so that I can move files that have an accesstime older than say like a month, but I am having issues with checking the access time of the files. The issue that I seem to be over writing the access time of the file when that is not what I am wanting to do. Why does this happen?

This is for checking file access times and comparing them to say a time frame of a month ago (obviously not done since I am having issues). I've tried using st_mtime and st_ctime, but those don't return the last time a file was accessed. The computer that I am coding this on is a Mac.

```
import os, shutil
import datetime as dt

downloads = "/Users/tomato/Downloads/"
os.chdir(downloads)

# list of files in downloads or specified directory
files_list = []

class file:
    def __init__(self, object):
        self.object = object
    def getLastATime(self): # prints out something that looks like this: 2019-04-03 which can be read as year-month-day
        return dt.date.fromtimestamp(os.stat(".").st_atime)

for files in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    files_list.append(file(files))
print(files_list[0].getLastATime())
```

My expected results for this when it prints out the first file in the directory is to see 2019-04-02, but what I get is 2019-04-04 which is today and not the last time I went to the file and actually opened it to view or use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class calls `os.stat(".")`. This will always get the stats of the current directory, not of the file the object was constructed with. (And because you've just accessed the directory with `os.listdir()`, the access time will be the current time.) Consider using `os.stat(self.object)` instead.

Also, don't call your class `file`. You're going to confuse people who are used to [the `file` class from Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#bltin-file-objects).